# How to enable fancy-routes for Pagy Gem in Rails 6 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, pagy

I'm trying to replace **?page=** with **/page/2** for all paginated pages in my Rails 6 application, so that I can be able to use Page Caching according to [this guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/caching_with_rails.html).

I'm using the Pagy gem for pagination and [according to their documentation](https://github.com/ddnexus/pagy/blob/master/docs/how-to.md#enabling-fancy-routes), I should be able to add a helper method to override to add support for fancy routes.

I've added this block to my application_helper.rb

```
def pagy_url_for(pagy, page)
  params = request.query_parameters.merge(pagy.vars[:page_param] => page )
  url_for(params)
end
```

However, after I do that I get this error:

```
 "undefined method `vars' for "__pagy_page__":String"
```

Any ideas on how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

I think they mixed up the params in their tutorial. Try

```
def pagy_url_for(page, pagy)
  params = request.query_parameters.merge(pagy.vars[:page_param] => page )
  url_for(params)
end
```

Comment: The documentation for the current version is correct, but it was missing the comment about the inverted order of the params in previous versions. Added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you `include Pagy::Frontend` in `application_helper.rb`?

```rb
# application_helper.rb
class ApplicationHelper
  include Pagy::Frontend

  def pagy_url_for(pagy, page)
    params = request.query_parameters.merge(pagy.vars[:page_param] => page )
    url_for(params)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `__pagy_page__` is a placeholder used in the frontend and in a number of extensions so the error that you report is not useful without a full backtrace.

Besides posting the backtrace here, you can also post your question in the specific [Pagy Support](https://gitter.im/ruby-pagy/Lobby) for a faster answer.